# Add timedelta to a date column above weeks

Tags: python, dataframe, timedelta, python-polars

How would I add 1 year to a column?

I've tried using `map` and apply but I failed miserably.

I also wonder why `pl.date()` accepts integers while it advertises that it only accepts `str` or `pli.Expr`.

A small hack workaround is:

```
col = pl.col('date').dt
df = df.with_column(pl.when(pl.col(column).is_not_null())
                    .then(pl.date(col.year() + 1, col.month(), col.day()))
                    .otherwise(pl.date(col.year() + 1,col.month(), col.day()))
                    .alias("date"))
```

but this won't work for months or days. I can't just add a number or I'll get a:

```
> thread 'thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'invalid or out-of-range date<unnamed>',
         ' panicked at '/github/home/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/chrono-0.4.19/src/naive/date.rsinvalid or out-of-range date:', 173:/github/home/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/chrono-0.4.19/src/naive/date.rs51
:note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Most likely because day and month cycle while year goes to infinity.

I could also do this:

```
df = df.with_column(
        pl.when(col.month() == 1)
        .then(pl.date(col.year(), 2, col.day()))
        .when(col.month() == 2)
        .then(pl.date(col.year(), 3, col.day()))
        .when(col.month() == 3)
        .then(pl.date(col.year(), 4, col.day()))
        .when(col.month() == 4)
        .then(pl.date(col.year(), 5, col.day()))
        .when(col.month() == 5)
        .then(pl.date(col.year(), 6, col.day()))
        .when(col.month() == 6)
        .then(pl.date(col.year(), 7, col.day()))
        .when(col.month() == 7)
        .then(pl.date(col.year(), 8, col.day()))
        .when(col.month() == 8)
        .then(pl.date(col.year(), 9, col.day()))
        .when(col.month() == 9)
        .then(pl.date(col.year(), 10, col.day()))
        .when(col.month() == 10)
        .then(pl.date(col.year(), 11, col.day()))
        .when(col.month() == 11)
        .then(pl.date(col.year(), 12, col.day()))
        .otherwise(pl.date(col.year() + 1, 1, 1))
        .alias("valid_from")
    )
```

Comment: Can you try with UDFs? https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-udf-user-defined-function/amp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polars allows to do addition and subtraction with python's `timedelta` objects. However above week units things get a bit more complicated as we have to take different days of the month and leap years into account.

For this polars has `offset_by` under the `dt` namespace.

```py
(pl.DataFrame({
    "dates": pl.date_range(datetime(2000, 1, 1), datetime(2026, 1, 1), "1y")
}).with_columns([
    pl.col("dates").dt.offset_by("1y").alias("dates_and_1_yr")
]))
```

```
shape: (27, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ dates               ┆ dates_and_1_yr      │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 │
│ datetime[ns]        ┆ datetime[ns]        │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 2000-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2001-01-01 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2001-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2002-01-01 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2002-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2003-01-01 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2003-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2004-01-01 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...                 ┆ ...                 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2024-01-01 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2024-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2025-01-01 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2025-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2026-01-01 00:00:00 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2026-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 2027-01-01 00:00:00 │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Which solution would be faster/better? With the apply method mentioned by @datenzauber.ai i don't have to calculate the leap year since i am adding years and not days. Is there any noticeable difference?

If i wanted to do the same with 1 month instead of 1 year, datenzaubers solution will be easy because i will always add 1 month with 1 line of code, but with your solution i would have to calculate how many days the given month has first. Is this correct?

Comment: Using polars expressions is always tons faster than custom python. I benchmarked it locally to be at least 300x faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `polars.apply` and `dateutil.relativedelta` which works for years, months, days and much more, but can be slow for lots of data.

```py
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

df = pl.DataFrame(pl.date_range(date(2019, 1, 1), date(2020, 10, 1), '3mo', name='date'))
df.with_column(pl.col('date').apply(lambda x: x + relativedelta(years=1)))
```

Update: Since the `offset_by` method is now also available for months, it should be used whenever possible (see accepted answer). I leave this answer here because the approach can be used for more complicated cases that are not supported by `offset_by`.